# Values in Java properties file didn't show up

Tags: java, struts2

I am learning Struts2. When I am in [Message Resource File sector](http://struts.apache.org/docs/message-resource-files.html), I wrote down some key value pairs in Java properties file and expected them show in form tag after a action class. However, they didn't show up.
They're supposed to look like this

[image]

Comment: please show the relevant code and read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the example tutorial the file should be in the same package folder as the action class. The maven structure divided the source folders to use `resources` for the properties files. See the [`Register.ptoperties` file](https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/blob/master/message-resource/src/main/resources/org/apache/struts/register/action/Register.properties) for the example of source code.

> Put the text below in a file named `Register.properties` in the `org.apache.struts.register.action` package in the `src/resources/java` folder.

Then you can use a `key` attribute of the `textfield` tag to retrieve resources for label.

> ```
> <s:textfield key="personBean.firstName"  />
> ```

Comment: Amazing! I forgot to post the source code and you 've solved my question! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to explore [showcase applications](https://github.com/apache/struts/tree/master/apps) that are really cookbook examples.